# Html style change

Tags: javascript, html

I have 8 functions like this. How i can change the style (width,color etc) of all the buttons?

```js
function my(){document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML="THIS QUESTION"+
"</br>"
+"<button onclick=answer1() id=ques1 >first answ</button>"
+"<button onclick=answer2() id=ques2 >sec answer </button>";
document.getElementById("go").innerHTML="";
}
```

Comment: CSS `button { width: 80px; color: red; }`

Comment: You mean in javascript code that you mentioned or by separate css?

Comment: In javascript or how i can add the link of separate CSS in this fragment?

Comment: Is question1 id of the button?

Comment: you should use single/double quotes to wrap html attr, like this:`'<button onclick="answer1()" id="ques1" style="width:80px;color:red" >first answ</button>'`

Comment: no its not of the button. I have no id for button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, add `css`

```
function my(){document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML="THIS QUESTION"+
"</br>"
+"<button css=‘btncss’ onclick=answer1() id=ques1 >first answ</button>"
+"<button css=‘btncss’ onclick=answer2() id=ques2 >sec answer </button>";
document.getElementById("go").innerHTML="";
}
```

And define `css`

```
.btncss
{
   width:200px;
}
```

Or if you dont want to add `css` in  javascript then add `style` for all buttons at once

```
button
{
  width: 200px;
}
```

Or you can use `input type= "submit"` instead of `button` and add general `css` for all `buttons` if you dont want to add `css` to `buttons` in javascript

```
input[type="submit"]
{
    width:200px;
}
```

then your javascript will be like

```
function my(){document.getElementById("question1").innerHTML="THIS QUESTION"+
"</br>"
+"<input type='submit' onclick=answer1() id=ques1 value='first answ'>"
+"<input type='submit' onclick=answer2() id=ques2 value='sec answer'>";
document.getElementById("go").innerHTML="";
}
```

> Note:General `css` like `button` will be applicable automatically in the html page referring it

Comment: Input type in separate css? and how does it looks in: +"<___ =answer2() id=ques2 >sec answer </button>";

Comment: Somehow I am not able to edit my post, @ami, you can also use button { width:200px;}

Comment: also added input suggested html